# Создание уникального поля

Tags: php, sql

Имеется функция, проблема в том что при INSERT-е если попадается уникальное поля, он выпадает ошибку после нескольких рефрешов инсерт происходит. Поле должно иметь от 8-12 ЦИФР. Проблема `FLOOR(RAND() * 4010000000) + 1000000000`
Пробовал UUID_SHORT так же:

```
function bookingCreate($hotelid, $roomid, $dtarrive, $dtdepart, $price, $email) {
$resultId = -1;

$cn = dbConnect();
$timearrive = strtotime($dtarrive);
$timedepart = strtotime($dtdepart);
$newformatarrive = date('Y-m-d',$timearrive);
$newformatdepart = date('Y-m-d',$timedepart);
        mysqli_query($cn,"INSERT INTO table(hotelid, roomid, dtarrive, dtdepart, userid, bookingcode, price, status, email) VALUES (".$hotelid.",".$roomid.",'".$newformatarrive."', '".$newformatdepart."',0, FLOOR(RAND() * 4010000000) + 1000000000, ".$price.", 1, '".$email."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bookingcode=FLOOR(RAND() * 4010000000) + 1000000000");
        $resultId = mysqli_insert_id($cn);
mysqli_close($cn);

return $resultId;
```

Comment: вам не кажется что тэги html и smarty в данном вопросе лишние?

Comment: а зачем вам свистопляска с рандомом? Почему бы просто не добавить инкрементальное поле?

Comment: Потому что нужно чтобы последовательность не возможно было отследить легким путем.

Comment: Отдайте свою проблему триггеру BEFORE INSERT. Он лучше справится. _нужно чтобы последовательность не возможно было отследить легким путем_ Джо потому и неуловимый, что его не ловят, ибо он никому нахрен не нужен...

Comment: А зачем вам непредсказуемые значения в БД ? Храните в БД обычные автоинкрементные id. А при общении с клиентом используйте их шифрованные каким нибудь AES представления.

Comment: Господа если строить, строить нужно по уму, если вы хотите сказать что Вы это не знаете, не нужно писать это в завуалированном стиле. Разве нельзя это контролировать в базе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение при котором повтор практически невозможен:

```
$orderIdUnique = rand(1,99)."".(time()-strtotime("2016-01-01 00:00:00"))."".rand(1,99);
```

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно изобретать велосипеды, все уже изобрели до нас: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Друг ты прям вовремя! Спасибо, но Джо выбрал свой тернистый путь!